# design relational data with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I'm building an App that use Mongo and my background is SQL databases.
 Need some help from NOSQL - document - specialists.

The domains relationships are:

```
User submitted many Links
Links has many Stars from different Users
User starred many Links
```

First, let me tell you what kind of queries I need.

The **'results'** below does not map the mongo schema, just what kind of response I desire.

**Return all submitted Links with a flag telling that the User already starred or not that link.**

```
 [
   { id: '2138912839', url: 'www.stackoverflow.com', stars: 30, starred: true, },
   { id: '9948729374', url: 'www.google.com',        stars: 1,  starred: false },
   { id: '9948729374', url: 'www.mongodb.com',       stars: 9,  starred: true }
 ]
```

**Return all Links that was starred by User**

```
  [
    { id: '998548734', link: { url: 'www.stackoverflow.com' } },
    { id: '995648478', link: { url: 'www.mongodb.com' } }
  ]
```

My first idea was use the embedded documents inside links to contains all starred users.

Link Schema:

```
{ id: MongoObjectId, url: String, stars: Number, starred: [ { userId: MongoObjectId }] }
```

But studying the length limit by document, 16MB I refuted this approach.
So, what else ? Use other collection ( Stars ).

Stars Schema

```
 { id: MongoObjectId, link: { url: String }, user: { id: MongoObjectId } }
```

The idea is pretty simple, replicate the link information inside Star. The drawback is that I will explode my database with the same information to every user that star the link.

Resuming what I have:

```
Links Collection 
   { id: MongoObjectId, url: String, stars: Number, starred: [ { userId: MongoObjectId }] }


Stars Collection      
   { id: MongoObjectId, link: { url: String }, user: { id: MongoObjectId } }
```

How can I return a flag indicating whether the user starred or not the link ? is there a better way to model ?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Rule of thumb: When you describe your data using the words "has many" in every sentence, you should be using a relational database.

Comment: but @Philipp, every real application contains relational data. are u telling me that you can only use mongo with no relational data, like logs, events ... ? Real application can not use mongo db? thanks

Comment: Not everything is a good match for MongoDb. Have you read MongoDb's DB modeling docs? http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/data-models/ the options are covered very well with the considerations for each.

Comment: hey @WiredPrairie, thanks you so much for the link. I agree with you (period).  
but imagine that is a requirement imposed to you. How do you accomplish that ? The second query I could satisfy not normalizing the data (done) the drawback is that will explode the database with repeated data. The first query, I can't figured it out how to do without two queries.

Comment: It may be necessary to send two queries.  Is that a problem?

Comment: Well, the design that I made, I can only retrieve what I need with two queries and 'join' in code the data. I don't know how to design differently to accomplish that. How do you design these requirements ? thanks

Comment: @WiredPrairie is not really a problem, I'm using angular and I am retrieving all links ( first query ) and after that I request another query to fetch only user starred links (second query). The 'join' is made in the client side. This was my approach to respond the requirement.

Comment: That technique is very common.